# failed load UIViewController to UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swiftui

```
struct DetailView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var data: Recipe

    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Detail", bundle: nil)
        let detail = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "detailViewController") as! DetailViewController
        detail.configure(recipe: data)
        return detail
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

This is my code, and all reference objects not found in `DetailViewController`

When I remove `as! DetailViewCotroller`, Xcode can find reference in `DetailViewController`

Comment: What is the question? What does "and all reference objects not found in `DetailViewController`" mean?